# what native libraries are included in DJI's Android SDK?

Tags: dji-sdk

Does anyone know what native libraries are included in DJI's Android SDK ? Or anyone know how I can find the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You can open your built APK file and check the lib folder.
The Github page for the SDK mentions FFMPEG libraries to be dynamically linked to the DJI SDK. My APK lib folder contains the following native libraries:

```
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libffmpeg.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libdjisqlcipher.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDJIUpgradeCore.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libFR.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libudt.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDexHelper_sdk.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDJICSDKCommon.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libyuv2.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libdjivideo.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDJIUpgradeJNI.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libFlyForbid.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libdjifs_jni.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libsfjni.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libudtjni.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libwaes.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDJICommonJNI.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/librtcm.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libUpgradeVerify.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libFRCorkscrew.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libGroudStation.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libartcm_jni.so"
ArchiveEntry: pathPrefix="", path="/lib/arm64-v8a/libDjiAffinity.so"
```